# Detecting/handling querytables failures

Tags: excel, vba

I know little about visual basic use with excel but I'm working on some existing code.  I pretty much have everything working provided that the querytables server responds.

I wondering if there's any way for me to detect the failure of the querytables operation?

Here's the code...

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range(Cells(row_stock, 27), Cells(row_stock + 199, 27))) ' was "AA7"
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
```

Comment: and what is the problem symptom?

Comment: What happens now when it fails?  Typically you would use `On Error Goto ...` to handle an error: do you have any type of error handling in your code?

Comment: @smirkingman: get error 1004 if server unreachable

Comment: @Tim Williams: I will look at On Error, thanks

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for the pointer to On Error.  As I said VB is new to me.  I added an error handler which retried web site timeouts several times and exited gracefully if retry count exceeded.  If you post an answer, I would accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens now when it fails? Typically you would use On Error Goto ... to handle an error.

If you're not familiar with handling errors in VBA then  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm is a good overview to get you started.